# How to define a URL in django that directly points to a static file?

Tags: django, django-urls

I have a urls.py file that looks like this:

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf import settings
from django.views.generic.base import RedirectView
from django.contrib.staticfiles.templatetags.staticfiles import static

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

I want to make a URL (say r'^test/' ) such that when I enter that URL, it directly links to a static file (say 'static/test.html').

Comment: do you have/create any app ?

Answer (score 0):

A simple way is you can use `redirect` function to do this.

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect
def test(request):
    return redirect(to="/static/test.html")
```

and point with your url to this function. I have tested and this works perfectly for me.